# Creating virtual directories in sub directories in IIS 6.0 (programmatically)

Tags: c#, iis-6, directoryentry

I am attempting to create virtual directories in IIS 6.0 programmatically and having problems checking if a virtual directory exists if the virtual directory is in a nested folder.

So if I have a folder tree such as:

```
MySite
  Folder A (virtual directory)
  Folder B
      NestedFolder C (virtual directory)
```

When I grab the DirectoryEntry object for this site metabase:

```
"IIS://<servername>/W3SVC/2/Root"
```

The DirectoryEntry object (will call it entry) will have two children, with

```
entry.Children[0].Name = "Folder A"
```

but entry.Children[1].Name = "Folder B" which is not a virtual directory.  I have to do the following (code) to get to any virtual directories in nested folders:

```
foreach (var directoryEntry in entry.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().Where(directoryEntry => directoryEntry.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebVirtualDir" || directoryEntry.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebDirectory")) {
            foreach (DirectoryEntry child in directoryEntry.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().Where(subChild => subChild.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebVirtualDir")) {
                if (child.Name == vDir)
                    return true;
            }

            if (directoryEntry.Name != vDir) continue;
            return true;
        }
```

Which to me is quite ugly.  Is there a better way that I can check for existing virtual directories if they exist in sub folders?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a recursive function to iterate the complete site?

```
public static void Main() {
    var siteRoot = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://<servername>/W3SVC/2/Root");
    var containsVirtualDirectory = ContainsVirtualDirectory(siteRoot);
}

private static Boolean ContainsVirtualDirectory(DirectoryEntry container) {
    foreach (DirectoryEntry child in container.Children) {
        if (child.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebVirtualDir")
            return true;

        if (child.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebDirectory" && ContainsVirtualDirectory(child))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```